# CSV import issue for MYSQL datetime field

Tags: mysql, csv

The below field is exist in CSV file.

```
Close Time
11-02-2015 12:02
10/31/2015 3:45:00 PM
```

I am using PHPMYADMIN for importing the field present in CSV file. In the table field declared as Datetime.

When i am importing the above 2 date values are not populating. Its just populating as 0000-00-00.

Please let me know how to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the format of date time in your CSV to make it compatible with MySQL format.
You can change your format in CSV by right click on column and select format cell.
Now change to date format and save the CSV and try to import.